# How to control sessions using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to realise "logged in system" policy which means only one session per login. But problem is that I have `sessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` and sessions actually doesn't exist. So how can I solve this task? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have a problem here. Since you're using `STATELESS` approach it means that Spring will not create any session: no security context, no cookies, every request must be authenticated on its own.